# \cite gives me question marks

Tags: bibliographies, editors

I think I'm having a compiler problem. If I try this:

```
    \documentclass[11]{article}

\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Having made a mybib.bib file as:

```
%%%%%%%%%%% mybib.bib %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
@BOOK{HK,
 AUTHOR={H. Kopka and P. W. Daly},
 TITLE={A Guide to LaTeX},
 PUBLISHER={Addison-Wesley},
 ADDRESS={Reading, MA},
 YEAR=1999.
 }
@BOOK{MG,
 AUTHOR={M. Goossens and F. Mittelbach and A. Samarin},
 TITLE={A LaTeX Companion},
 PUBLISHER={Addison-Wesley},
 ADDRESS={Reading, MA},
 YEAR=1994.
 }
@ARTICLE{Pan,
 AUTHOR={D. Pan},
 TITLE={A Tutorial on MPEG/Audio Compression},
 JOURNAL={IEEE Multimedia},
 YEAR={1995},
 VOLUME= {2} ,
 PAGES={60-74},
 MONTH={Summer}.
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Boney96,
AUTHOR={L. Boney and A. H. Tewfik and K. N. Hamdy},
TITLE={Digital Watermarks for Audio Signals},
booktitle={Proceedings of the Third IEEE International Conference on
Multimedia},
PAGES={473-480},
MONTH={June},
YEAR={1996}.
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% end %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

When I compile, I don't even generate a .pdf file. Why so?

Comment: Please see question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number?rq=1. Possible duplicate!

Comment: For some reason, bibtex has not created a .bbl file for me. What does that mean? And how do I run bibtex?

Comment: The closing dot in your new  example bib file is wrong, change it to comma!  Not `YEAR={1996}.` but `YEAR={1996},`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29508/discussion-between-kurt-and-civilsigma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I corrected your given code.

Please see the now compiling MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Silent.Spring,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title  = {Silent Spring},
  month  = {September},
  year   = {2015},
  url    = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Spring},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item The main finding of the book ``Silent Spring'' was that the 
    use of the use of DDT pesticides was killing birds and harming the 
    environment. Also, she described how DDT entered the food chain 
    and accumulated in the fatty tissues of the birds , animals and 
    humans and how that caused cancer and genetic 
    damage\cite{Silent.Spring}.
\end{enumerate}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Package `filecontents` is used to have one code, including the bib file (`texdoc filecontents`on your terminal/console for more informations).

The key is not allowed to contain a blank: so I changed your `Silent Spring` to `Silent.Spring` (don't forget the `\cite` command!)

You opend an `enumerate` environment, but you didn't close it.  I deleted these lines.

All these errors caused that your bib file could not be included. Now it should work.  With MiKTeX I run `pdflatex mwe.tex`, then `bibtex mwe`, then two times `pdflatex mwe.tex` from the console / terminal  with the result:

[image]

Comment: I use TExMaker, how would I run those?

Comment: I noticed that \bibliographystyle{plain} is in a yellowish/orange color instead of blue like on many tutorial videos. Is that the problem?